# Trying to make a java program creating 2 moving rectangles

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to programming graphic applications in java and I'm having some trouble with this one in particular, what it should do is that it should create two rectangles moving right to left. my issue is that for some reason the program does move the rectangles but doesn't show the rectangles and when it does they are for some unknown reason glitched with only two sides visible. here's the code:

Rectangle's class:

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
public class TubeComponent extends JComponent
{
    private final static int WIDTH = 20;
    private Rectangle up, down;
    private int windowLength;
    private int windowWidth;
    public TubeComponent(int aWidth, int aHeight)
    {
        windowLength = aWidth;
        windowWidth = aHeight;
        up = new Rectangle();
        down = new Rectangle();
        up.setLocation(windowWidth, 0);
        int newHeight = (int)((windowLength - WIDTH) * Math.random());
        up.setSize(WIDTH, newHeight);
        down.setSize(WIDTH, windowLength - newHeight - WIDTH);
        down.setLocation(windowWidth, (int) (up.getHeight() + WIDTH));
    }

    public void randomize()
    {
        up.setLocation(windowWidth, 0);
        int newHeight = (int)((windowLength - WIDTH) * Math.random());
        up.setSize(WIDTH, newHeight);
        down.setSize(WIDTH, windowLength - newHeight - WIDTH);
        down.setLocation(windowWidth, (int) (up.getHeight() + WIDTH));
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.draw(up);
        g2.draw(down);
        System.out.println("ascissa " + getX() + " ordinata " + getY() + " altezza " + getHeight() + " larghezza " + getWidth());
    }

    public void moveBy(int dx, int dy)
    {
        up.translate(dx, dy);
        down.translate(dx, dy);
        repaint();
    }

    public int getX()
    {
        return (int) up.getX();
    }

    public int getY()
    {
        return (int) up.getY();
    }

    public int getHeight()
    {
        return (int) up.getHeight();
    }

    public int getWidth()
    {
        return (int) up.getWidth();
    }
}
```

Frame class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Scene extends JFrame{
    private final static int HEIGHT = 400;
    private final static int WIDTH = 500;
    private final static int SPEED = 4;
    private final static int PING = 1;
    private TubeComponent tube;

    public Scene()
    {
        tube = new TubeComponent(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        add(tube);
        setSize(HEIGHT, WIDTH);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("flappy");
        ActionListener a = new TimeListener();
        Timer t = new Timer(PING, a);
        t.start();
    }

    private class TimeListener implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            tube.moveBy(-1, 0);
            if(tube.getX() < -1*tube.getWidth())
            {
                tube.randomize();
            }
            System.out.println("ascissa " + tube.getX() + " ordinata " + tube.getY() + " altezza " + tube.getHeight() + " larghezza " + tube.getWidth());
        }
    }
}
```

Executable class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FrameViewer {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scene s = new Scene();
    }  
}
```

I've left the print command to show that the rectangle is actually there and isn't out of bounds. I've tried simplifying the class (by making it print  a still rectangle to see if it was my computer but even though it still didn't work, by programming another project with just a still rectangle and that works.

Comment: Try making `TubeComponent` extend `JPanel` rather than `JComponent` and also the first line in the overridden `paintComponent` method should [usually] be `super.paintComponent(g)`. Have you seen this Web page? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html

Comment: I always found that trying to do animation in Swing was much hard / much more work than what it should be. If I were in your shoes today, I would start by looking on GitHub for some swing animation libraries that could make the process easier

Comment: Are you aware that methods `getX()`, `getY()`, `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`, in class `TubeComponent`, override methods in class `javax.swing.JComponent`?

Comment: @Abra, yes i was aware but since i tried them i thought that since they always returned 0 they weren't actually working methods ( it actually sounds very dumb but that was my first thought). i actually rewrote the code without overriding them and now it works. No idea how they created artifacts on the window but now it's fixed

Comment: *"since they always returned 0.."* They don't. *"..they weren't actually working methods"* They are. It's just that you seem to be testing them at the wrong time. They only acquire a definitive size once added to a visible container and the top level window is packed to size.